# Rails - submitting JSONs to database from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, controller

I am working on a Rails app, and I am attempting to insert attributes from JSONs as database entries.  I'm running into a problem, though, and would appreciate some guidance.

I've been able to jam a few things together and come up with something that sort of works...

```
def create
    @report_group = Array.new

    @report_group.push({location:"home", comments:"Hello, database!"}, {location:"away", comments:"Goodbye, database!"})

    @report_group.each do |x|

        @new_report = Report.new(x)
        @new_report.user_id = current_user.id

        @new_report.save
    end
end

private
def report_params(params)
    params.permit(:user_id,:location,:comments)
end
```

This is a good first step - this commits two entries to my database, one for each of the hashes pushed into @report_group, but it is suffering from a problem - the create action does not reference the `report_params` whitelist.

I have built several Rails apps where entries are submitted one at a time via the standard Rails form helpers, but I have never done it with multiple JSONs like this before. Trying out the syntax I'd use in a typical form helper situation

```
@new_report = Report.new(report_params(x))
```

throws the expectable error `undefined method permit' for #<Hash:0x007f966b35e270>` but I am not sure what else to do here.

**EDIT TO SHOW SOLUTION**
Big thanks to @oreoluwa for pointing me in the right direction.  Here's the solution that I came up with.

```
def create
    @report_group = Array.new

    @report_group.push({location:"home", comments:"Hello, database!"}, {location:"away", comments:"Goodbye, database!"})

    @report_group.each do |x|

        hash = ActionController::Parameters.new(x)

        @new_report = Report.new(report_params(hash))
        @new_report.user_id = current_user.id

        @new_report.save
    end
end

private
def report_params(params)
    params.permit(:user_id,:location,:comments)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because a `Hash` is not the same as an `ActionController::Parameters`. In order to use the `permit` method with your `Hash` you may need to first convert it to `ActionController::Parameters`, as such:

```
hash = {location:"home", comments:"Hello, database!"}
parameter = ActionController::Parameters.new(hash)
parameter.permit(:user_id,:location,:comments)
```

I don't know if that is what you're looking for, but I thought to point you in the right direction.

Comment: THANK you! Wow, this really helps me to understand how this system works.  Editing my question above to show the solution that worked for me.